# Reset ABAddressBookGetAuthorizationStatus

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ios6

Im am currently developing an app that can access the user Address Book. The first time I tried the app on my device, I got the ABAddressBookGetAuthorizationStatus alert showing and working. My problem is that now I would like to debug what happens if the user denies the authorization, but, even If I delete the app from the Xcode organizer, every time I install the app again for debug, the phone remembers that I already authorized the app to access my contacts. To make things clearer, I would like to know how to reset this authorization so that I can get the alert shown again and so respond to the deny event... Any help over this would be very much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

reset it the settings app of the iphone/ipad (or mac)

Comment: This works, of course, thanks... I was just wondering if there was a way to avoid resetting the hole phone settings for this. But it's fine since I didn't find any other way to do it.